# Documentum Method Server to call a method On Startup

Tags: jboss, documentum, documentum6.5

Is there a way to trigger a method/job when the JBoss of Documentum Method server has started automatically?
I want to call a java method when the JBoss method server has started.
Any inputs are  much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a way to do this without writing some amount of custom code.  You could continuously monitors the state of the service, or the changes to the JBoss log file.  Or you could attempt to piggyback this code into the batch/cmd file used to start JBoss.

Another option is to create a Documentum job that runs frequently, and it would obviously be triggered after JBoss has started up.  You could use some means to check how long it has been since the job last ran (believe this could be in the dm_job table), and determine if the code inside needs to be executed, or just exit the job.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I think will take this direction to proceed further.